# MySQL - Search for a product by many categories (many rows...) faster?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

I have a large set of data (ie 20 milions row of each table) which looks kind of like this (I'm not really dealing with products and catogories, but the same kind of situation)

Table products

```
|id|name|created_at|
--------------------
|1 |....|2018-06...|
|2 |....|2018-06...|
|3 |....|2018-06...|
|4 |....|2018-06...|
|5 |....|2018-06...|
...etc.
```

And a table of categories

```
|id|product_id|category|description|
------------------------------------
|1 |1         | abc    | def       |
|2 |1         | ghi    | jkl       |
|3 |1         | mno    | pqr       |
|4 |2         | abc    | stu       |
|5 |2         | wvx    | yz        |
...etc
```

What I want to do is a search, to find products with many categories, ie.

```
SELECT DISTINCTROW * FROM product WHERE

product.id in (
    SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category = 'abc'
)
AND
product.id in(
    SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category = 'ghi'
)
AND
product.id in(
    SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category= 'mno'
)
AND 'some extra where' ORDER BY product.created_au LIMIT 10 offset 0
```

But this is really slow... I've tried different approaches on this, but everyone takes at least 30 seconds.

I've made index of the columns used for joining.

So basicly I want to do a search where a product have to match one or many categories. Also, later on, I want to search so that a product matches a category and a description (might be from different rows in categories table).

Any ideas? Or perhaps links where I can read more about cases like this?

Comment: Have on sub-query to return the abc and ghi and mno product_id's. JOIN with that sub-query.

Answer (score 2):

A temporary table should help speeding up things.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmpCategories( category_id INT)
```

Find a way to insert the ids of the category that you want to search for into this table.

Then write a join similar to this:

```
SELECT p.* FROM product p
INNER JOIN categories c ON p.product_id = c.product_id
INNER JOIN tmpCategories tc ON tc.catrgory_id = c.category_id
```

Your query might not be exactly like this. But this approach may speed things up.

P.S.  I'm typing from my phone so pardon the formatting :)

Answer (score 1):

First suggestion you could use INNER JOIN on subquery instead of IN

```
    SELECT DISTINCTROW * 
    FROM product p 
    INNER JOIN  (
        SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category = 'abc'
    ) t1 on p.id  = t1.product_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category = 'ghi'
    ) t2 on p.id = t2.product_id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category= 'mno'
    ) t3 p.id = t3.product_id
    WHERE  'some extra where' 

    ORDER BY product.created_au LIMIT 10 offset 0
```

You could also try using a single subquery for obtain all the product_id with the 3 category

```
    SELECT DISTINCTROW * 
    FROM product p 
    INNER JOIN  (
       SELECT categories.product_id FROM categories WHERE category IN ( 'abc','ghi', 'mno')
       group by categories.product_id 
       having count(distinct category ) = 3
    ) t1 on p.id  = t1.product_id
    WHERE  'some extra where' 

    ORDER BY product.created_au LIMIT 10 offset 0
```

If the inner join doesn't speed up as expected, then be sure you have proper composite index on categories table

```
 CREATE INDEX index_name  ON categories(category,product_id );
```

Comment: The `categories` table is really big (20 milion rows) which takes a lot of time to search in (tried your solutions, thanks! but it didn't speed up things thats much). I don't own the database at the moment, but it looks like it needs a redesign, perhaps thats the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` to get the products:

```
select c.product_id
from categories c
where c.category in ('abc', 'ghi', 'mno')
group by c.product_id
having count(*) = 3;
```

You can use `join`, `exists`, or `in` to get the rest of the product information:

```
select p.*
from products p join
     (select c.product_id
      from categories c
      where c.category in ('abc', 'ghi', 'mno')
      group by c.product_id
      having count(*) = 3
     ) cp
     on c.product_id = p.i
where . . .  -- other conditions on product
```